# zend_mm_heap corrupted error

Tags: php, zend-framework

У меня есть скрипт на php, который работает используя pthreads. То есть многопоточность. Чтобы запустить несколько потоков я создаю несколько экземпляров класса, который и делает основную работу. В классе я обращаюсь к БД MS SQL и использую cURL. После того, как я запущу два или более потока с этими классами, с некоторым шансом вылезает ошибка zend_mm_heap corrupted. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить?
Code:
https://pastebin.com/vb5eRHM6

Comment: Акселератор какой-либо есть? Opcache например? Загаси его.

Comment: @de_frag Да гасил уже, все из гугла перепробовал...

Comment: Тогда например strace в помощь, если это на линуксе каком. А там уж как повезет.

Comment: @de_frag винда сервер 2016((